# Difference between clicking the minimize button on a JFrame vs. calling setstate or clicking the taskbar?

Tags: java, jframe, jna

I currently have an application with a heavyweight Canvas component and it crashes when I minimize the JFrame. It does not stop working if I minimize using setstate or double click the taskbar icon so I'm left wondering what's different about the call on the window icon/button.